# Azure B2C login issue

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

When I run signupsignin user flow in Azure B2C portal to test Open ID Connect (external Azure Tenant login), received below error.

Sorry, but we're having trouble signing you in.
We track these errors automatically, but if the problem persists feel free to contact us. In the meantime, please try again.

Correlation ID: 6744ccb7-eb8d-47f6-bb0a-bcd2f84f5771
Timestamp: 2021-08-04 04:10:53Z
ConnectionTimeOut: An exception has occurred.

Comment: You need to see what the exception is in Application Insights - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/troubleshoot-with-application-insights

Answer (score 0):

This [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/active-directory/error-sign-into-app) describes a similar error that occurs when you try to sign in to an app that's set up for Azure AD B2C

> **Cause:** The client ID may be missing or incorrect in the Web.config file for the app.
>
> **Resolution**
>
> To fix this issue, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Open the Web.config file for the app.
> 2. In the Web.config file, find the app key ida:ClientId.
> 3. Replace the value of the app key with the client ID that is provided for your app in the Azure AD B2C admin portal.
>
> The changed part of the file resembles the following:
>
> ```
> <appSettings>
> <add key="ida:ClientId" value="**xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx**">
> </appSettings>
> ```

**References:**

1. [troubleshooting-with-application-insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/troubleshoot-custom-policies#troubleshooting-with-application-insights)
2. [azure-ad-b2c-importing-in-users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42555234/azure-ad-b2c-importing-in-users)

Answer (score 0):

Could be the case:
Make sure you are using the API Key and API Key Secret.
Not the ClientId and Client Secret

[image]
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-twitter?pivots=b2c-user-flow